# Graphing correctly a quadratic function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, coordinates

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1:6]
\draw[very thin, color=green, step=0.2cm](-2,-3) grid (7,11);
\draw[color=cyan](-2,-3) grid (7,11);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-2,0)--(7,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-3)--(0,11) node[left]{$y$};
\foreach \x in {-1,0,...,6}
\draw (\x cm, 1pt)--(\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {-2,-1,...,10}
\draw (1pt, \y cm)--(-1pt, \y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\draw[color=black, thick] plot (\x,\x^2-5*\x+4) node[]{$y=x^2-5x+4$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the first coordinate should have been (-1,10) but my code is plotting (-1,8). Other points appear to be okay. The function is y=x²-5x+4

Please, my requests are as follows:

1. Help me correct this code so that the graph would pass through (-1,10) as it should, instead of (-1,8)
2. I would be glad if the label (y=x²-5x+4) is sloped and along the curve instead of hanging on top.

[image: Graph of y=x²-5x+4]

Comment: Try `\draw[color=black, thick] plot (\x,\x*\x-5*\x+4)` instead `\draw[color=black, thick] plot (\x,\x^2-5*\x+4)`

Comment: Or `\draw[color=black, thick,smooth,samples=100] plot (\x,\x*\x-5*\x+4) node[]{$y=x^2-5x+4$};`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @ChikaOdiliobi, if you liked answer, you can upvote it or even accept :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Culprits of your problem is `\x^2` in your function. Correct is `(\x)^2`.

Try:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.style = {very thick, draw=gray, -{Straight Barb[length=1mm]}},
domain=-1:6, samples=70
                        ]
\draw[very thin, color=green, step=0.2cm](-2,-3) grid (7,11);
\draw[color=cyan](-2,-3) grid (7,11);
\draw[arr] (-2,0) -- (7, 0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[arr] (0,-3) -- (0,11) node[left]{$y$};
% tick labels
\foreach \x in {-1,0,...,6}
\draw (\x, 1pt) -- ++ (0,-1pt) node[below left] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {-2,-1,...,10}
\draw (1pt, \y) -- ++ (-1pt, 0) node[below right] {$\y$};
% function
\draw[color=black, thick] plot (\x,{(\x)^2 - 5*\x+4}) 
    node[anchor=north east, rotate=80] {$y=x^2-5x+4$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} need for Straight Barb[length=1mm].

Comment: @M.Ahmadi, you are right! This line was lost during updating of MWE ... :-(. Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Zarko the line `node[xshift=1em, anchor=east, rotate=80] {$y=x^2-5x+4$};` could be improved by replacing the options with `node[anchor=north east, below, sloped] {$y=x^2-5x+4$};`, I think.

Comment: @Alenanno, checked. You are right. Corrected. Thank you very much!

Comment: So I guess in the evaluation step, `\x^2` becomes `-1^2` which gets interpreted as `-(1)^2`, ie -1 instead of 1.

Comment: @DanRobertson, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative solution with `pgfplots`, I haven't changed your plot command.

### Output

[image: graphic plot image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
            domain=-1:6,
            yscale=2,
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel={\large $x$},
            ylabel={\large $y$},
            xtick={-1,...,6},
            ytick={-2,...,10},
            ymin=-3,
            ymax=11,
            xmin=-2,
            xmax=7,
            grid=both,
            grid style={line width=.1pt, green},
            major grid style={line width=.2pt,cyan},
            minor tick num=4,
            tick style={draw=none},
            extra x ticks={-2,6,7},
            extra y ticks={-3,10,11},
            extra x tick labels={},
            extra y tick labels={},
            extra x tick style={grid=both},
            extra y tick style={grid=both},
        ]
        \addplot[thick,smooth, cyan!50!green] (\x,\x^2-5*\x+4) node[]{$y=x^2-5x+4$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I'm grateful.